# Animated Ripples using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, adobe-edge

I would like to create an animated visualisation (responsive if possible) where the ripples are originating from a central point and when those ripples reach outer nodes in a circle, those nodes create similar ripples of variable size.

So far, I have found these libraries:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

http://flare.prefuse.org/

But none of them seem to have exactly what I am after and they also seem like an overkill.

What is be the best approach to achieve this?

**P.S:** I am open to using Adobe's Edge Animate if it offers an easy solution since I create a lot of data visualisations for the new company I am working with.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be either to use some [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) or possibly to use HTML5 canvas and JavaScript with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

[here](http://codepen.io/daless14/pen/ELFgj) is an example of creating a ripple effect with CSS animations on CodePen

```
.ripple:before,.ripple:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
}
.ripple:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay:.2s;-moz-animation-delay:.2s;top:5px;left:25px;
}
.ripple:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay:.8s;-moz-animation-delay:.8s;top:25px;left:0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rip 
{
  0%  {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 0 transparent,
               0 0 0 0 transparent,
               0 0 0 0 transparent,
               0 0 0 0 transparent;
  }
  5%  {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 0 #45c2c5,
               0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4),
               0 0 0 0 #45c2c5,
               0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow:0 0 40px 200px #45c2c5,
               0 0 10px 210px transparent,
               0 0 30px 220px #45c2c5,
               0 0 5px 230px transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution. Any way of creating more ripples when the outgoing ripples reach an element (this element will be the origin of new ripples) located at XX Pixel radius?